# How to debug Qt-application installed via Flatpak

Tags: debugging, qt, gdb, flatpak

I'm trying to enable debug for QOwnNotes application installed via Flatpak (following this tutorial: [Debugging a Flatpak application](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2017/01/20/debugging-a-flatpak-application/)).

I have installed application itself and debug parts for its Sdk and itself:

```
$ flatpak install flathub org.qownnotes.QOwnNotes
$ flatpak install flathub org.qownnotes.QOwnNotes.Debug
$ flatpak install flathub org.kde.Sdk.Debug//5.14
```

Then launching application with:

```
$ flatpak run --command=sh --devel org.qownnotes.QOwnNotes
```

And running it via `gdb`:

```
sh-5.0$ gdb /app/bin/QOwnNotes 
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3.1
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /app/bin/QOwnNotes...
(No debugging symbols found in /app/bin/QOwnNotes)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /app/bin/QOwnNotes 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff27be700 (LWP 9)]
[Detaching after fork from child process 10]
```

But it is unable to find debugging symbols.

Comment: Try to `run flatpak run --command=sh --devel org.qownnotes.QOwnNotes.Debug` this is where the debug symbols are supposed to be.